# If f is a linear transformation on a finite dimensional vector space V...

Tags: linear-algebra

If f is a linear transformation on a finite dimensional vector space V satisfying $f^2=f$, explain how to find a diagonal matrix representing f

This is a workbook question im lost on, could someone pls advise the process here?

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

- $\sigma(f)=\{0,1\}$
- $V= \text{Im}(f) \oplus \text{ker}(f)$
- $f(x)=x,\forall x \in \text{Im}(f)$
- take the basis for $\text{Im}(f)$ and a basis for $\text{ker}(f)$ to form a basis for $V$. The matrix representation of $f$ under the basis is of the  form $$\text{diag}\Big\{\underbrace{1,1,\cdots,1}_{\text{number of 1's=rank f =trace f} },0,0,\cdots,0\Big\}$$

**Added**:

Let $\{u_1,u_2,...u_m\}$ be a basis for $\text{ker}(f)$. So it can be extended to a basis for $V$ namely $B=\{u_1,\cdots,u_m,v_1,v_2,\cdots,v_n\}$. Hence $\text{Im}(f)=\text{span}\{v_1,...,v_n\}$

Now to compute the matrix of $f$, start with $$f(u_1)=0=0\cdot u_1+\cdots+0 \cdot u_m+0 \cdot v_1+\cdots+0 \cdot v_n$$ $$\vdots  $$ $$\vdots  $$ $$f(v_n)=v_n=0\cdot u_1+\cdots+0 \cdot u_m+0 \cdot v_1+\cdots+1 \cdot v_n$$ Hence the matrix of $f$ has the form $$\begin{pmatrix} 0 &0 & \cdots & 0 &0 &0\\  \\ \vdots\\0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 1& 0 \\\\0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots&0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$$

Answer (score 1):

Sketch: Observe that for any $\vec{v}\in V$, we can write 
$$\vec{v}=(\vec{v}-f(\vec{v}))+f(\vec{v}).$$
We observe that $\vec{v}-f(\vec{v})$ is in the kernel of $f$ since
$$
f(\vec{v}-f(\vec{v}))=f(\vec{v})-f^2(\vec{v})=0.
$$
On the other hand, $f(\vec{v})$ is fixed by $f$ since $f(f(\vec{v})=f^2(\vec{v})=f(\vec{v})$.

I claim that this representation is unique.  In fact, suppose that 
$$
\vec{v}=\vec{w}_1+\vec{w}_2,
$$
where $\vec{w}_1$ is in the kernel of $f$ and $\vec{w}_2$ is fixed by $f$.  Then, 
$$
f(\vec{v})=f(\vec{w}_1)+f(\vec{w}_2)=\vec{w}_2.
$$
It then follows that $\vec{w}_1=\vec{v}-f(\vec{w})$.

At this point, we directly get that
$$
V=\ker f\oplus\operatorname{image} f.
$$
Then, $f|_{\ker f}$ is identically zero, while $f|_{\operatorname{image} f}$ is the identity.  Both of these restrictions can be diagonalized, so the diagonalization is given by an orthonormal basis for the kernel combined with an orthonormal basis for the image.

Note that this argument implies that $f$ has an eigenbasis and the only eigenvectors for $f$ are $0$ and $1$ (which can be justified in other ways).